# Prove that $Y = \frac{X_1+X_2*X_3}{\sqrt{1+X_1^2}}$ obeys normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

given that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent and identically distributed, $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$.

I tried to calculate the cumulative distribution function of Y:
\begin{align}
P(Y\leq y) &= \underset{\frac{x_1+x_2x_3}{\sqrt{1+x_1^2}}\leq y}{\iiint}f(x_1)f(x_2)f(x_3)\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2\mathrm{d}x_3\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x_1 \underset{x_2x_3\leq y\sqrt{1+x_1^2}-x_1}{\iint}f(x_1)f(x_2)f(x_3)\mathrm{d}x_2\mathrm{d}x_3\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}
and then derive the probability density function of $Y$. But I can't figure out the above integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asks:

> Prove that $Y = \frac{X_1+X_2*X_3}{\sqrt{1+X_1^2}}$ obeys normal distribution

How about a proof that it doesn't?

Here is a quick Monte Carlo check of the empirical pdf of $Y$:

[image]

which is decidedly not Normal.

What is the source of your question?

Comment: My junior classmate asked me this question. Since it's false, should I delete this question, or modify it?