# Proving that the $\frac {\xi +\zeta\eta}{\sqrt {1+\zeta^2}}$ has normal distribution (0,1)

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

The task: $\xi, \eta, \zeta \sim N(0,1)$ and independent. Prove, that $\frac {\xi +\zeta\eta}{\sqrt {1+\zeta^2}} \sim N(0,1).$ (1)

It is clear, that with fixed $\zeta$ we get, that (1) has expected value = 0 (as the sum of normal distributed values) and variance = 1 (as the sum of $(\frac {1}{\sqrt {1+\zeta^2}})^2$ and $(\frac {\zeta}{\sqrt {1+\zeta^2}})^2$). And what to do with un-fixed value I don't know. There was a small tip -imagine, that $\zeta$ is discrete value (for example getting 3 different values) and use the full probability formula $(P(B)=\sum P(B|A_{j})P(A_{j}))$.

Comment: You need to assume that $\xi, \eta, \zeta$ are _independent_...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, yes, I have forgotten to add this)

Comment: This indicates it doesn't

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021455/prove-that-y-fracx-1x-2x-3-sqrt1x-12-obeys-normal-distribution?rq=1

Perhaps the variables are not independent after all?

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin, there is an another type of "equation". It has small differences

Comment: Calculate the characteristic function $E\exp(itR)$ of your ratio $R$  by conditioning on $\zeta$ and noticing that the conditional expectation does not depend on $\zeta$.

Comment: I think,  that the calculations of E in that case will be very difficult and there is an another way

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=\frac{\xi+\zeta\eta}{\sqrt{1+\zeta^2}}$. You want to show $E\exp(itR)=\exp(-t^2/2)$.  Write $E\exp(itR)=E(E[\exp(itR)|\zeta])$.  The inner, or conditional expectation is $$\begin{align*}E[\exp(itR)|\zeta]&=\tag{*}
E\exp(it\xi/\sqrt{1+\zeta})|\zeta) \times E\exp(it\eta/\sqrt{1+\zeta})|\zeta)\\
&= \exp(-\frac{t^2}{2(1+\zeta^2)}) \exp (-\frac{t^2\zeta^2}{2(1+\zeta^2)})\\
&= \exp(-\frac{t^2}2).
\end{align*}$$
The first step, at (*), is because $\xi$ and $\eta$ are conditionally independent given $\zeta$.
So the outer expectation is also $\exp(-t^2/2)$.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!